# Laravel average of numbers per group

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, average

For my project, I want students to see the average grade per school subject.

```
$grades = Auth::user()->student->grades()
    ->with('subject')->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->get()->groupBy('subject_id');
```

Now I first get the grades with the subject and then group them by subject.
How can I add the average grade per subject group?

**Table columns**

[image]

Comment: You have to show more clearly. We can't guess what columns are there.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the table columns.

Comment: You can have what you want in a single query, but your question isn't providing us with enough info.

Comment: @JosephAjibodu The grades are now grouped by the subject_id. Now I want per subject_id the average grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest would be to select all rows with subject id X, loop through and and add all the scores to a total, then divide that total by the `count()` of the rows returned.

A nicer way might be through crafting a cool SQL query that does the same, but that's for you to decide, this is roughly how you do it.

Comment: I did this to get the average grade per school subject.

```$averages = [];
        foreach ($grades as $key => $grade) {
            $averages[$key] = $grade->avg('number');
        }```